# window.open method doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

I am using this code:

```
<input type="image" value="submit" src="map.png" id="location" onclick="window.open(location.html)" />
```

But when I click on my picture, a black window is shown although I have some white text as this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport"
content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0"> 
<meta name="description"
content="A single-page template generated by Tizen Wearable Web IDE" />

</head>
<body>
<p><font color="white">Today is sunday!</font></p>
</body>
</html>
```

What's wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Strings in Javasrcript need to be quoted. It should be:

```
onclick="window.open('location.html')"
```

Otherwise, it treats `location` as a variable name.

Answer (score 0):

Try using location.href instead of location.html if you want to open the current page in a new window else use simple quotes e.g. 'example.html'.